# Error while uploading Networkit python module with Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, dylib, networkit

I installed the Networkit module with `conda install -c vgauthier networkit`.  If I import it in a notebook (`import networkit as nk`) I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a4c0096fb06c> in <module>()
----> 1 import networkit as nk

//anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkit/__init__.py in <module>()
     41 # local imports
     42 from . import stopwatch
---> 43 from . import graph
     44 from . import graphio
     45 from . import community

//anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkit/graph.py in <module>()
      1 # extension imports
----> 2 from _NetworKit import Graph, SpanningForest, GraphTools, RandomMaximumSpanningForest, UnionMaximumSpanningForest

ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_NetworKit.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_NetworKit.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Anyone able to explain why?
​

Answer (score 1):

I happened to have the same problem for networkit via pip. It is because the networkit installed by anaconda does not link to your gcc compiler correctly, a simple fix is to download the networkit's source code and run `python3 setup.py install` to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:
https://github.com/kit-parco/networkit/issues/172

It's because of anaconda Python. Re-install it using:

```
conda install -c vgauthier networkit
```

Answer (score 0):

installing it with conda instead of pip solved the problem for me. See instructions [here](https://github.com/networkit/networkit#conda-channel-conda-forge).